# firefox mime type add wrong extention

Tags: firefox, openxml, mime-types

With spreadsheet such as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

If a similar MIME-TYPE file has already been downloaded then when trying to open it frefox will add a .xlsx to the correct .xls extension making it un-openable

Comment: Did you tried with a different mimetype such as vdn.application/xml

Comment: yes but it mark it as oppen with XML editor, wich work but I'd preffer open with excel direcly for my clients

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a glitch that has already been reported:

[Bugzilla link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1388677)